# Spark load a csv into JavaPairRDD by key found in row

Tags: java, apache-spark

I want to load a csv into a JavaPairRDD, using a value in the row as the key, and the row itself as the value. Currently I am doing it like this:

I have a csv that has lines like this:

```
a,1,1,2
b,1,1,2
a,2,2,3
b,2,2,3
```

I have a java object that represents these rows like this:

```
public class FactData implements Serializable{
    public String key;
    public int m1;
    public int m2;
    public int m3;
}
```

I'm currently getting to the pairRDD like this:

```
JavaRDD<FactData> lines = sc.textFile("test.csv").map(line ->  FactData.fromFileLine(line));

JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<FactData>> groupBy = lines.groupBy(row -> row.getId());
```

But I am wondering if there is a faster/better way to do this? something like:

```
JavaPairRDD<String,Iterable<FactData>> groupedLines = sc.textFile("test.csv").flatMapToPair(new PairFlatMapFunction<String, String, Iterable<FactData>>() {
    @Override
    public Iterator<Tuple2<String, Iterable<FactData>>> call(String s) throws Exception {
        //WHAT GOES IN HERE?
        return null;
    }
});
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use keyBy.?

Let's say, you want first value of the file as key and total line as value. 
Than you can do this simply.

```
JavaRDD<String> lines = context.textFile("test.csv");
JavaPairRDD<String, String> newLines = lines.keyBy(new Function<String,String>(){
        @Override
        public String call(String arg0) throws Exception {
         return arg0.split(",")[0];
        }   
    });
```

If you want collect as Map, may be you can do this.

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<String>> newLines = lines.keyBy(new Function<String,String>(){

            @Override
            public String call(String arg0) throws Exception {
                return arg0.split(",")[0];
            }           
        }).mapValues(new Function<String, Iterable<String>>(){
            @Override
            public Iterable<String> call(String arg0) throws Exception {
                return Arrays.asList(arg0.split(","));
            }
        });
```

Comment: this seems to give me back only 1 row when I collectAsMap (the first one in the file)

Comment: why do u want to collect as map.?

Comment: I need my end result to be this: JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<FactData>>

Comment: If you want to collect as you, you need add one more wrapper around it.. I just added edit.